# Get Ektron Form Post Back Message from API

Tags: ektron

Using Ektron 8.02, I'm trying to retrieve the Post Back Message of an Html Form using only the API. I haven't been able to find a property on the `Ektron.Cms.FormData` object which provides this, nor any method in the `Ektron.Cms.API.Content.Form' class which will retrieve it. Is what I'm trying to do even possible through the API or should I instead attempt to get this from the database directly?

Answer (score 0):

I've found it. To get all of the data from an Html Form you'll need to get the form as `FormData` and `ContentData` objects. Inside the `ContentData.Teaser` property is a bit of `XML` that contains the postback message among other things. Will have more information after I get back to my work machine.